# Как распарсить массив byte которые изначально лежали в файле *.gz

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, gzip

Есть sitemap и в нём ссылки на файлы с расширением gz. Я их скачиваю с помощью requests.get и получаю массив byte. Как их распаковать, не записывая их в промежуточный файл?
P.S Внутри архива лежит текстовый файл.

Comment: Попробуйте модуль gzip: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Answer (score 0):

[Попробуйте](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/33be1723873f7ce2b3617c99530d5e06a4fd8f69/gzip_examples/main.py):

```
# rs = requests.get...
# ...
 
import io
byte_io = io.BytesIO(rs.content)

with gzip.open(byte_io) as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    print(file_content)
```

---

Пример скачивания файла из сети, я не использовал `requests`, потому что тот `url` возвращает в своем заголовке, что данные сервер передаст сжатыми `gzip`, а `requests` достаточно умный чтобы сам сделать расжатие, в отличии от `urlopen`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen('http://httpbin.org/gzip') as rs:
    bytes_data = rs.read()
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(bytes_data)

    with gzip.open(byte_io) as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        print(file_content)
```

---

Примеры из документации: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage

---

[Это интересно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), `gz` это архив для одного файла:

> В соответствии с традициями UNIX-программирования, gzip выполняет
> только две функции: сжатие и распаковку одного файла; упаковка
> *нескольких файлов в один архив невозможна*.